# Prevent infinite loop in useEffect when setting state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently building a scheduling app.  If a user selects two dates, I am attempting to select all date blocks between the two selected dates in the calendar as well.  I am able to achieve this, but it causes my useEffect to fire into an infinite loop because I have state as a dependency in my useEffect where I am setting state.  I am unsure of the best method to prevent the infinite loop behavior. The useEffect in question is the bottom one.  My code is as follows:

```
export default function App() {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(
    dayjs().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
  );
  const [events] = useState([
    {
      id: "5e24d1fa-aa66-4122-b1eb-97792f0893b0",
      name: "Rodriquez Family",
      selectedDates: ["2021-05-01"],
      status: "submitted"
    },
    {
      id: "269a0381-63c7-4ab6-92d8-7f7b836aee6f",
      name: "Test Family",
      selectedDates: ["2021-05-03"],
      status: "submitted"
    }
  ]);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const getDaysArray = async (firstDay, lastDay) => {
    let dates = [];
    var dow = dayjs(firstDay).day();
    while (dow > 0) {
      dates.push(null);
      dow = dow - 1;
    }

    while (firstDay <= lastDay) {
      dates.push(firstDay);
      firstDay = dayjs(firstDay).add(1, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    }

    return dates;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getDates = async () => {
      const firstDay = dayjs(selectedDate)
        .startOf("month")
        .format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      const lastDay = dayjs(firstDay).endOf("month").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      const dates = await getDaysArray(firstDay, lastDay);

      const list = dates.map((date) => {
        const event = events.find(({ selectedDates = [] }) =>
          selectedDates.includes(date)
        );
        return event ? { date, event } : { date, event: null, checked: false };
      });

      setData(list);
    };
    getDates();
  }, [events, selectedDate]);

  const selectDate = (date) => {
    setData(
      (a) =>
        a &&
        a.map((item) =>
          item.date === date ? { ...item, checked: !item.checked } : item
        )
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data && data.filter((res) => res.checked).length > 1) {
      const filterDates = data.filter((r) => r.checked);
      const startDate = filterDates[0].date;
      const endDate = filterDates[filterDates.length - 1].date;

      const datesToUpdate = data.filter(
        (res) => res.date > startDate && res.date < endDate
      );

      const newArr = data.map((date) => {
        const updateCheck = datesToUpdate.find((r) => r.date === date.date);

        return updateCheck ? { ...updateCheck, checked: true } : date;
      });

      setData(newArr);
    }
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DayJsUtils}>
      <div className="App">
        <DatePicker
          minDate={dayjs()}
          variant="inline"
          openTo="year"
          views={["year", "month"]}
          label="Year and Month"
          helperText="Start from year selection"
          value={selectedDate}
          onChange={handleDateChange}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="cal">
        <div className="cal-div1"></div>
        <div className="cal-div2 "></div>
        <div className="cal-div3 cal-cir-hov"></div>
        <div className="cal-div4"> SUN </div>
        <div className="cal-div5"> MON </div>
        <div className="cal-div6"> TUE </div>
        <div className="cal-div7"> WED </div>
        <div className="cal-div8"> THU </div>
        <div className="cal-div9"> FRI </div>
        <div className="cal-div10"> SAT </div>
        {data &&
          data.map((r, i) => {
            return (
              <>
                <div
                  onClick={() =>
                    !r.checked &&
                    r.date >= dayjs().format("YYYY-MM-DD") &&
                    !r.event &&
                    selectDate(r.date)
                  }
                  style={
                    r.checked
                      ? { backgroundColor: "green" }
                      : { color: "#565254" }
                  }
                  key={i}
                  className="cal-cir-hov"
                >
                  <div>{r.date} </div>
                  <div
                    style={
                      r.event?.status === "submitted"
                        ? { color: "orange" }
                        : { color: "green" }
                    }
                  >
                    {r.event?.name}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  );
}
```

attached is a code sandbox for debugging and to show the behavior I am currently talking about.  Select two separate dates that are greater than today and you will see all the dates in between are selected, but the app goes into a loop https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-snow-03r59?file=/src/App.js:301-4499

Comment: The rule is that effects should never update your state. They're two different things - effects update part of the UI _outside_ of the standard stateupdate->render mechanism. It's a long read, but go through https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html anyway, especially if you haven't fully read it in its entirely at least once before.

Comment: paraphrasing: "Are you saying effects shouldn't set state?" No, I'm not: the React documentation is. Effects are "side effects that happen every time a component updates". If you make them update the state, now they're no longer side effects, they are a functional part of your component's state management, and you shouldn't be using `useEffect` for whatever functionality you've written up. Again: it's a long page, but read it anyway. It is the most authoritative source, and well written, documenting exactly what `useEffect` is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your useEffect depends on a variable that you're updating on the same useEffect there will always be the re-render and cause a loop.

If you want it to execute only once, you should remove the `data` variable from the useEffect dependency array.

But if you really wanna mutate the state every time that the `data` variable changes, my recommendation is to create another state for the mutated data.

For example `setFormattedData` would not change the data itself, but you would still have a state for this data in the format that you want.

Comment: Understood and you think there's no way around this but to use two separate states

Comment: You could create a function instead of a useEffect and call it programatically when you need to update the state, this would prevent a loop like the one in the useEffect, because the useEffect will always execute again when its dependencies update.

Comment: whenever you select a date `selectDate` creates a brand new data and sets it . when you have a dependency in the form of array or object react does shallow comparison where it compares only the reference of the previous array and the current array . since you created a new array . The reference keeps changing which causes the useEffect to run in infinite loop . we should always be passing primitives in the dependency array .

Comment: can you clarify what a primitive is?

Comment: just was curious if you could provide a little more details on what a primitive is

Comment: The primitives he's referencing to are the primitive types in javascript, wich is `string, number, boolean, null, undefined, symbol`, it does not include arrays and objects and are more recommended for use in useEffects.